# PHP SQL Count 3 column totals and group by another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to put together an SQL query where I can count 3 columns and group by another one.

Here is the table:

id thedate cars bikes planes from stats group by thedate

**What I'm trying to do is to get the totals for each day of each cars, bikes and planes.**

So I've tried:

```
SELECT id, thedate, cars, bikes, planes from stats GROUP BY thedate

SELECT id, thedate, count(cars), count(bikes), count(planes) from stats GROUP BY thedate
```

None of them work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(thedate), count(cars), count(bikes), count(planes) from stats GROUP BY DATE(thedate)
```

You should group by date only (without hours and minutes) and shouldn't select an id field.

Comment: Your script works perfect as sql and trying it on phpmyadmin and the result is correct. What I was using it for was for google charts, but using your sql makes the chart dissapear. I know your answer is correct but I just wondered if you know why the chart will not plot when using your sql with multiple counts? Here is the relevant part for the google chart:

Comment: function drawVisualizationdailyChart() {

                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ // Create and populate the data table.
                    ['Date', 'Cars', 'Bikes', 'Planes'],
                    <?php
                    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                        extract($row);
                        echo "['Date: {$thedate}', {$cars}, {$bikes}, {$planes}],";
                    }
                    ?>
                ]);

Comment: Maybe you need name your count() columns:
SELECT DATE(thedate) AS thedate, count(cars) AS cars, count(bikes) as bikes, count(planes) AS planes from stats GROUP BY DATE(thedate)

Comment: @Tim3880 is right. Try this one SELECT DATE(thedate) AS thedate, count(cars) AS cars, count(bikes) AS bikes, count(planes) AS planes from stats GROUP BY DATE(thedate)

Comment: Yeah I tried that too but still no chart appearing :o/  I know you answer is correct so I'll have to ask this as another question, unless you have another idea of what I could try